# Changing ACPI thermal values

Tags: battery

I am trying to reuse an old laptop(HP Pavilion Entretainement dv7), however I am continously encountering with an overheating problem. I don't know if this affects, but the computer is unable to boot with the charger unplugged(only boots with when charging). I did successfully install the Kali Linux OS.

Here are some commands that made me think that the problems are mainly with the battery:

```
└─# upower -e
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_ACAD
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice

└─# upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               Hewlett-Packard
  model:                Primary
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sat Sep  2 16:20:15 2023 (16 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               pending-charge
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              0 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         73.44 Wh
    energy-full-design:  73.44 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    charge-cycles:       N/A
    percentage:          0%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-caution-charging-symbolic'

└─# acpi -V              
Battery 0: Not charging, 0%, rate information unavailable
Battery 0: design capacity 5100 mAh, last full capacity -51 mAh = -1%
Adapter 0: on-line
Thermal 0: ok, 66.0 degrees C
Thermal 0: trip point 0 switches to mode hot at temperature 100.0 degrees C
Thermal 0: trip point 1 switches to mode passive at temperature 95.0 degrees C
Cooling 0: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 1: LCD 8 of 10
Cooling 2: Processor 0 of 3

└─# cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/trip_point_0_temp 
100000

└─# cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/trip_point_1_temp
95000

└─# ls /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0 
available_policies  cdev0_weight      cdev1_weight  integral_cutoff  k_po  offset  slope              temp               trip_point_0_type  trip_point_1_type
cdev0               cdev1             device        k_d              k_pu  policy  subsystem          trip_point_0_hyst  trip_point_1_hyst  type
cdev0_trip_point    cdev1_trip_point  hwmon0        k_i              mode  power   sustainable_power  trip_point_0_temp  trip_point_1_temp  uevent
```

Anyone knows or has any idea of how I can end with the overheating problem(without having to purchase any new equipment).

Thanks for reading!

Comment: What overheating problem? Your battery is dead.